# Draw Text over Draw Bitmap

Tags: android, eclipse, text, bitmap

I have a bitmap and a text. I just wanted to place a text over my bitmap but the problem is the text is drawn behind the bitmap. Can anyone help me?

```
     canvas.drawText("10", (mazeFinishX1 * totalCellWidth)
            + (cellWidth / 10), (mazeFinishY1 * totalCellHeight)
            + (cellHeight * 0.75f), ball);
     canvas.drawBitmap(lvl1_portal1, (mazeFinishX1 * totalCellWidth)
            + (cellWidth / 20), (mazeFinishY1 * totalCellHeight)
            + (cellWidth / 20), ball);
```

I already test it. the text appears behind the bitmap.

Comment: if you post your code, maybe somebody could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First draw the bitmap, then the text.

```
 canvas.drawBitmap(lvl1_portal1, (mazeFinishX1 * totalCellWidth)
        + (cellWidth / 20), (mazeFinishY1 * totalCellHeight)
        + (cellWidth / 20), ball);
 canvas.drawText("10", (mazeFinishX1 * totalCellWidth)
        + (cellWidth / 10), (mazeFinishY1 * totalCellHeight)
        + (cellHeight * 0.75f), ball);
```

Order matters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. You draw in wrong order.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(lvl1_portal1, (mazeFinishX1 * totalCellWidth)
            + (cellWidth / 20), (mazeFinishY1 * totalCellHeight)
            + (cellWidth / 20), ball);
     canvas.drawText("10", (mazeFinishX1 * totalCellWidth)
            + (cellWidth / 10), (mazeFinishY1 * totalCellHeight)
            + (cellHeight * 0.75f), ball);
```